# CS:GO will not launch on Ubuntu 16.04 with Radeon HD 7640G

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon, ubuntu-drivers

Just want to preface this by saying that I have looked at all other similar question, and no suggested answers have worked so far, so sorry if this is a duplicate question.

I am trying to tun CS:GO on Ubuntu 16.04, the graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 7640G I have tried installing new drivers, but when I installed [these drivers](https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), I was unable to log in.

I did a fresh install, and here I am now, I feel like I've tried everything. can anyone help me out here please :)

Answer (score 0):

Your card does not appear to be compatible with the AMD GPU PRO driver, so using it is likely why it didn't work. You should be fine using the default open source driver AMD GPU (not pro) that is available with the fresh install. So in short do after fresh install update your system `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`. You can also use more up-to-date mesa package if you want, google for "ubuntu install mesa ppa" and look at obiaf or padako. Personally I didn't install either of these and I'm using AMDGPU driver (not pro) with RX 480, getting around 80fps on 1600x900 display (I'm stuck with an old monitor at the moment) but I've had it running at 1080p and 4k nicely before on a 4k TV that quit after 2 months (cheapie 4k tv so I'm saving to buy something a bit better).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick response, i tried what you said, but i got the same problem. I open steam and when i click csgo it says it is running but it doesn't open, any other suggestions?

Comment: There are often issues with steam and library files. Run `steam` from a terminal and look through the console output for clues as to why steam won't run (you may see something like libGL error: file missing) or wrong ELF class for example. Take a look at the Arch wiki for troubleshooting Steam problems [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Steam/Troubleshooting), the Arch wiki's are usually fairly detailed. Otherwise google your issue. AskUbuntu here will also have a lot of previous requests around Steam